# React setState with complex objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In our React components, we receive an object from a REST api (lets say a Car), allow the user to make changes, and eventually save the result.

To facilitate this we've created a custom react hook to receive the state. An example might look as follows:

```js
type Car = {
  brand: string,
  color: string
}

type Props = {
  // A service that handles cars
  service: Service<Car>
}

function CarEditor(service: Service<Car>) {

   const { loading, error, resourceState } = useService(service);

   return <form>
     <input value={resourceState.brand} />
     <input value={resourceState.color} />
   </form>;


}
```

In the above example, `resourceState` will have the type `Car`.

I'm struggling a bit on how to make modifications to this car. One idea is that we use a call to `setState` to make this object managed:

```js
function CarEditor(service: Service<Car>) {

   const { loading, error, resourceState } = useService(service);

   const [ car, updateCar ] = useState(resourceState);

   return <form>
     <input value={resourceState.brand} />
     <input value={resourceState.color} />
   </form>;

}
```

*Note: I left the event handlers out for brevity*

Questions:

1. Should I use 1 call to useState for each property of `Car`. This seems like a lot of repetition for complex objects, but I worry that using an entire object is an anti-pattern.
2. Would it be better for `useService` itself to expose a `updateResourceState` function, and completely contain the state of the Car, as opposed to having `useState` calls in the main component?

Pretty new to all this, and I'm trying to design this in a way that follows best practices, and has the least amount of surprise for seated React devs.

Comment: I feel this is kind of opinionated, but FWIW I would wrap the useService hook in another hook that manages the state unless you really need to move that functionality into the useService hook itself. I don't think having to handle it in the component is the right way though.

Comment: Thank you, I have control over useService, so I might just add it there.

Comment: That might be for the best. Don't forget though that you can always wrap a hook in another hook much like any function to compose different logic and maintain a nice clean separation of concerns. The only React-specific part is that you have to follow the rules of hooks.

Comment: It better to add your `useService` code to have a best suggestion

Comment: FYI by default, each call to `setState` starts a new render pass in react so separating into separate fields could even have performance implications https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/ (Disclaimer: could be a premature optimization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is not an anti-pattern if you store a complex object in a state in functional component, it's recommended to use `useReducer`. And your `resourceState` which has type of `Car` is not complex at all.
2. Depends on your `useService`. If you store `resourceState` as a state in `useService` you can just make a update `resourceState` function in `useService` and call it in `CarEditor` component, it will be clean and easy to maintain.